# Where do these extra characters come from from a user's profile name?

Tags: c#, string, sharepoint-2010, user-profile

When I'm evaluating a SharePoint list's custom field of type 'User' I'd expect to only get the username but instead I'm seeing additional characters at the start that I need to trim out.

`SPContext.Current.ListItem[NameOfUserField]` has the value of

"14;#DeeMac"

And as a side note - this field is being treated as a string - but in my xml files I've defined it as a 'User' field type - where and why has this conversion been made? I did originally try to cast it as `SPFieldUser` which failed.

Comment: what do other username strings look like?

Comment: Would you normally expect to see an AD domain name prefixing the username?  Not suggesting I know the answer btw... just that I wondered if something odd was going on in that regard that might give you a clue as to what's going on.

Comment: Not usually no, this seems to be a conversion done somewhere from user to string. I think I'm going to delete this question to be honest - I've found a solution to my original problem of how I'd go about interrogating the user field properly: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/32017/how-to-read-an-user-field-value-for-a-list-item/32023#32023

Comment: Rather than delete, maybe just leave up in case others get this issue when taking the same approach you'd taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the string is that user's ID in the `SPWeb` in question. I.e. DeeMac is, roughly speaking, the 14th person to use that web.

In order to get an `SPUser` object from that `string`, you need to take the `SPWeb` to which the user belongs and call the [`SPFieldUserValue(SPWeb, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458798) constructor with the two.

The `SPFieldUserValue` thus constructed contains a `User` property of type `SPUser`, which may be null if the string was null/empty.

Note that sometimes, I think, a user column may actually contain `SPFieldUserValue` objects already, instead of `string`s.

Also if it's a multi-user column, it might contain a `SPFieldUserValueCollection` object or a `string` to pass into *that* class's [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms441658).

If you ever run into issues, debug and check what's actually in your column.